# Trazer informações deduas tabelas "models" relacionadas através do ObjectId em uma única rota de API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodemon, módulo-ecmascript

Tenho duas tabelas "models" relacionadas através do ObjectId, como faço para que a API traga a informação das duas tabelas em uma única chamada ?

```
const Corporacao = mongoose.model('Corporacao',{
    nome: String,
    razao: String,
    cnpj: String,
    status: Boolean,
}) 

const Unidade = mongoose.model('Unidade',{
    nome: String,
    corporacao_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Corporacao'},
    razao: String,
    status: Boolean,
})
```

Na minha rota de API

```
//Buscar Unidade por ID
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) =>{
    // extrair o dado da requisição, pela url = req.params
    const id = req.params.id

    try {
        const unidade = await Unidade.findOne({_id: id})

        if(!unidade) {
            res.status(424).json({message: 'Unidade não foi encontrada'})
            return
        }

        res.status(200).json(unidade)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: error}) 
    }
})
```

Como eu faço para ao buscar a **Unidade** já trazer informações sobre a **Corporação** ?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver alterando a busca para:

```
const unidade = await Unidade.findOne({_id: id}).populate('corporacao_id');
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).